# Clear list except specific child

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I'm working with a list that I add and remove content from dynamiclly. However one `li` child should remain as it contains a form to add children to its parent. My problem is that calling `empty()` on the list also clears out the form child. I've tried using the `:not` on the form child's class: This sort of works, the actuall `li` item remains, but all form html is removed.

**JavaScript**

```
$('.singleList li:not(.newWish)').empty();
// Alternate version (same result)
$('.singleList li:not(.newWish):not(.newwishList)').empty();
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="singleListWrapper" style="display: none;">
    <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="a" data-divider-theme="a"
    class="singleList">
        <!-- Other children will be dynamically added here -->
        <!-- Everything from here .... -->
        <li class="newWish">
            <div data-role="collapsible" data-theme="b" data-content-theme="c">
                    <h2>Legg til ønske</h2>

                <ul data-role="listview" class="newwishList">
                    <li data-role="fieldcontain" data-theme="a">
                        <label for="name">Ønskets navn:</label>
                        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="newWishName"
                        value="" />
                    </li>
                    <li data-role="fieldcontain" data-theme="a">
                        <label for="slider">Antall:</label>
                        <input type="range" name="slider" id="slider" data-theme="a"
                        class="newWishAmount" value="0" min="0" max="100" />
                    </li>
                    <li data-role="fieldcontain" data-theme="a">
                        <label for="price">Pris:</label>
                        <input type="text" name="name" id="price" class="newWishPrice"
                        value="" />
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </li>
        <!-- ... To here should remain after empty() -->
    </ul>
</div>
```

**HTML after .empty()**

(Sorry about the bad formating due to all the jQm addded classes. The important
thing is the structure)

```
<li class="newWish ui-li ui-li-static ui-btn-up-a ui-last-child">
    <div data-role="collapsible" data-theme="b" data-content-theme="c" class="ui-collapsible  ui-collapsible-inset ui-corner-all ui-collapsible-themed-content">
        <h2 class="ui-collapsible-heading ui-li-heading"><a href="#" class="ui-collapsible-heading-toggle ui-btn ui-fullsize ui-btn-icon-left ui-btn-up-b" data-corners="false" data-shadow="false" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="span" data-icon="plus" data-iconpos="left" data-theme="b" data-mini="false"><span class="ui-btn-inner"><span class="ui-btn-text">Legg til ønske<span class="ui-collapsible-heading-status"> click to collapse contents</span></span><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-shadow ui-icon-minus">&nbsp;</span></span></a></h2>
        <div class="ui-collapsible-content ui-body-c" aria-hidden="false">
            <ul data-role="listview" class="newwishList ui-listview">
                <li data-role="fieldcontain" data-theme="a" class="ui-field-contain ui-body ui-br ui-li ui-li-static ui-btn-up-a ui-first-child"></li>
                <li data-role="fieldcontain" data-theme="a" class="ui-field-contain ui-body ui-br ui-li ui-li-static ui-btn-up-a"></li>
                <li data-role="fieldcontain" data-theme="a" class="ui-field-contain ui-body ui-br ui-li ui-li-static ui-btn-up-a ui-last-child"></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

Comment: `newwishList` is `ul` element not `li` element .

Comment: I know. I only added it to see if it had any effect, which it didn't.

Comment: I am sorry, I don't understand what you want to remove, and what to save.

Comment: I think you're just missing a space in the selector. Shouldn't it be `.singleList li:not(.newWish) :not(.newwishList)`?

Comment: @pktangyue Sorry about that. Updated to the HTML to hopefully make it clearer.

Comment: Why don't you clone the li before emptying the parent container and then reappend it later on?

Comment: @PetrVostrel Don't think so. Adding a space broke the remove.

Comment: in `Wish items will be appended here`, which are these `items`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because that `li` items of `newwishList` are also child of `.singleList` and are also selected by selectors of jQuery because they do not have a class of `newWish` and are emptied.

Instead of adding classes you can also use this:

```
$(".singleList li:not(.newWish):not([data-theme=a])").remove();
```

[Fiddle for Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/CvDZQ/1/)

And you can use `:not` psuedo class.

Comment: Excellent. Adding a class to the children of the form child did the trick!

Comment: Even better. Thanks again.

Comment: Just a quick note: It seems I have to call remove() rather then empty() as list-diviers steam to stack (remain as bloat) on empty() - If you want to update your answer.